# Potential consequences of providing voluntary work for a team I've been forced to leave

Tags: etiquette, outreach

I have been forced to leave my previous institute by my former principal investigator.

At the institute I have solved problems regarding the software, and I enjoyed giving help as much as I can to many users, even after resignation. I had a request from users to do a tutorial video.

I was thinking of that before resignation, but I am afraid that could be not favourable by the ex-PI. Although, a week ago I have received a message from him apologizing for what he did and wishing me good luck. Despite his behaviour, I forgive him.

I would really like to do that video voluntarily, but I am not belonging to the institute anymore and I would like to keep things good and not fabricating sensitivity. Should I ignore the request of those potential users or do those tutorials on my own?

Comment: Given your history with this PI (as you've revealed through questions here) I'd strongly recommend you not do that, whether "allowed" or not. As Solar Mike suggests, move on.

Comment: okay buffy, my intention was to engage myself also do something I really love to do. However, I think that you are right.

Comment: @Monika, remember a thing is a thing, how do we name is largely driven by perception. If you insist your departure is tragic and sad, it'd remain so. You'll need to learn how to unpack this and move on. Seek guidance through professionals (e.g. career coach, external mentors, mental health professionals, etc.) as you don't need to face this alone.

Comment: @Penguin_Knight, actually it not about regretting the lab I left, when I asked to do a video, because I have a deep desire to do it. Besides that, my story is little bit complex more than that, I have lost my Mom and later grand ma and I have a selfish father he was always destroying us, and I become somehow financially responsible for my siblings, although I am in a foreign country, so it was  a source of income, and the current position is for two months at an isolated european country and it is not granted to give me salary

Comment: , so it is not either good situation, but I am looking for long term position again. Finally, I am sick since four years and must get married since that time, but I didnot work out. I am sorry, but these all rushing on my mind, I have been always successful, diligent, but this is the maximum, although I love people, help, never be selfish, I wish oneday, I open my eyes, and all I have dreamed for years come true.

Comment: I know it is unprofessional to write that, and get bored to speak, but I need to be in a good mind state, I am alone here in a foreign country, and struggle for the dream I told mom when I was young I dont want to be an ordinary girl, I want to be an important woman, but every thing is going against me.

Comment: There will always be more things to do that can help people, if you look for them. If you speak a second language and you enjoy teaching, maybe you can volunteer teaching or reconnect with members of your native community that way. Otherwise maybe you could volunteer with the needy or the elderly, etc. But I would let this one go and find something (anything) new to do.

Comment: As a side comment I suggest you to avoid self-aggrandizing expectations. You press yourself to impress your family while insisting on bad relationships -- this can be your doom. If you have spare time and want fast, impressive results work on learning languages (spoken, programming) and outreach (wiki pages, merchandising your work). It takes a lot of effort but eventually it'll show. Don't work for parasites. Good luck !

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I strongly suggest you to move away from this person (your ex-adviser). Your relationship past history says it all, from your other posts. 
He only seeks to exploit you and couldn't care less about your wishes and opinions. Manipulative people are simply like that. Apologizing letters, a friendly smile, a tap on the back, a small gift, some unexpected public compliment, these are all bait. As you see, it's all of matter of giving them whatever you can.

Focus on yourself and aligning with positive peers. Find the good collaborators.

Good luck!

Answer (score 22):

Personally, I think you should focus that time and effort into getting another position, if you have not got one already.

If you have a new position already, well done, then focus that time and effort into where you are now. They, hopefully, will appreciate that effort and motivation.

Comment: May be I am foolish person and too emotional, actually I am in a short time contract, and the place is not so much good, and I have the time to do that video in any case, as I am really so motivated and I want to do activities like that. In any case, I think you are right, and I feel sorry how I looks very stupid.

Comment: You are not stupid, you had the bad luck to meet a poor advisor. Best of luck with the future.

Answer (score 2):

I would strongly recommend to ask your former PI, mentioning that many users asked for a video and that you would volunteer to produce it without any strings attached.

If he agrees, go for it. If not, move on.

I would not do it without consent (even though you might have the right to do it as long as you don't mention secrets).

Answer (score 2):

First, sorry that you were being forced to leave, hope you can find a better place to work.

As for your question, I'd like to think more objectively by asking these questions:

1. Do you feel you will enjoy creating that tutorial?
2. Will that tutorial be useful?
3. Do you have time for creating the tutorial?

If the answer to those questions are "yes", then I guess it would be good for you to create the video tutorial, as it will also help users in fully utilizing the software, which will help their work as well.